# What are the specifics for Laravel Query Builder's updateOrInsert function?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

This function is not in the Laravel documentation; I have found it in the source code; however, I am not entirely sure how it should be used. For example, if I am working with products, I want to insert or update a product in the database based on its UPC. If a product with the same UPC exists, update it with the new values. If not, insert the new values as a new product. How should this be done using this function?

Comment: updateOrCreate returns the model, whereas updateOrInsert returns a boolean value, but they do the same thing. but it's pretty much what you're looking for. Check out the docs for updateOrCreate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Insert or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with values.

```
updateOrInsert(array $attributes, array $values = [])
```

https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_updateOrInsert

```
DB::table('products')->updateOrInsert(
    [
        'upc' => $request->get('upc'),
    ],
    [
        'upc' => $request->get('upc'),
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'vendor' => $request->get('vendor'),
        'description' => $request->get('description')
    ]
);
```